# In Win10 is there a way to have the windows key open search?

Tags: search, windows-10, start-menu, windows-search

After the whole Win8 mess I got into the habit of opening things pressing the windows key and typing. It also works the same on my Ubuntu laptop. But now I've upgraded to Win10 pressing windows opens the start menu and typing does nothing.

It seems that to open programs by typing their name I have to open the search menu either by clicking or remembering to hit win-s. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: It shouldn't do that; the Windows key should allow you to start typing immediately

Comment: It already does.   It works identically to Windows 8.1 with regards to this

Comment: It really doesn't, I wonder if this is related to upgrading. I have the panel down the left of the screen, and I had some xmouse settings tweaked, could one of those be related?

Comment: I undid some of the xmouse regedit changes that I was using under Win8 and now typing into the start menu is working, although at the cost of focus follows mouse